# IIS 7 rewrite rule - rewrite same page, one or multiple query string parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webforms

I have the following rewrite rules setup

```
<rule name="Department Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^products/([^$]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="products?durl={R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Product Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^products/([^$]+)/([^$]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="products?durl={R:1}&amp;purl={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

The Department Rewrite works as expected and now I'm trying to configure the Product Rewrite to work.

With the URL *products/department*

- **Request.QueryString["durl"]** outputs *department*

With the URL *products/department/product*

- **Request.QueryString["durl"]** outputs *department/product*
- **Request.QueryString["purl"]** is NULL

How do I go about getting Product Rewrite to work as expected?

**UPDATE**

Also looking at how to ignore the URL rewrites if they contain `action/edit`. For example

```
products/department/action/edit
products/department/product/action/edit
```

Assuming I need to apply some conditional statements but unsure how to write them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `[^$]` trying to do? 
In the department rewrite, the first group is saying "matching anything but a $", which is the rest of the url, so that rule applied, and it's all in durl.

Try these, which are saying "match anything but a slash". I also like putting a $ to end it, if you know that's the full url (it can still have querystring parameters). That will make the product skip past the department rule.

In department rule:

```
<match url="^products/([^/]+)$" />
```

In product rule:

```
<match url="^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" />
```

I like the consistency that both groups are the same, but you could make the second one take anything, for a simpler rule:

```
<match url="^products/([^/]+)/(.+)" />
```

A side suggestion: put the more-specific rules first, so if you send in just one level (department), it definitely won't match the product rule. The way it is now, the department grabbed the product rule. If they were reversed, it probably would have worked, even without updating the rules.

Comment: Your suggestions have done the trick. Any ideas how I can negate if the URL contains "/action/edit"?

Comment: What's the whole url you're trying to avoid?